# Custom Photo-Browser Framework7 Template

Tags: html-framework-7

How I can build a Custom PhotoBrowser Framework7-Ver3 Page which its contain an input text can accept image index number.

in documentation I see theirs option "renderPage", but when I use it I got an **empty page**...how I can run photoBrowser with custom layout or what is html template most be return in "renderPage" method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found an answer by get template from generated html in framwork7**

so that, I will set generated template here, and you can remove or add any custom/build component.

```
1) renderPage: function(){
            return `<div class="page photo-browser-page photo-browser-page-dark no-toolbar" data-name="photo-browser-page">
                        <div class="navbar">
                            <div class="navbar-inner sliding">
                                <div class="left">
                                    <a href="#" class="link  icon-only back">
                                        <i class="icon icon-back color-white"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="title">
                                    <span class="photo-browser-current"></span>
                                    <span class="photo-browser-of">of</span>
                                    <span class="photo-browser-total"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="right"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="toolbar tabbar toolbar-bottom-md toolbar-hidden toolbar-transitioning">
                            <div class="toolbar-inner">
                                <a href="#" class="link photo-browser-prev">
                                    <i class="icon icon-back color-white"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="link photo-browser-next">
                                    <i class="icon icon-forward color-white"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="photo-browser-captions photo-browser-captions-dark">

                        </div>
                        <div class="photo-browser-swiper-container swiper-container swiper-container-virtual swiper-container-horizontal swiper-container-rtl swiper-container-android">
                            <div class="photo-browser-swiper-wrapper swiper-wrapper">
                                <div class="photo-browser-slide photo-browser-slide-lazy swiper-slide swiper-slide-prev"
                                     data-swiper-slide-index="0">
                                    <div class="preloader swiper-lazy-preloader color-white">
                                        <span class="preloader-inner">
                                          <span class="preloader-inner-gap"></span>
                                          <span class="preloader-inner-left">
                                              <span class="preloader-inner-half-circle"></span>
                                          </span>
                                          <span class="preloader-inner-right">
                                              <span class="preloader-inner-half-circle"></span>
                                          </span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="swiper-zoom-container"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="photo-browser-slide swiper-slide swiper-slide-active" data-swiper-slide-index="0">
                                    <span class="swiper-zoom-container"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="photo-browser-slide photo-browser-slide-lazy swiper-slide swiper-slide-next"
                                     data-swiper-slide-index="1">
                                    <div class="preloader swiper-lazy-preloader color-white">
                                        <span class="preloader-inner">
                                          <span class="preloader-inner-gap"></span>
                                          <span class="preloader-inner-left">
                                              <span class="preloader-inner-half-circle"></span>
                                          </span>
                                          <span class="preloader-inner-right">
                                              <span class="preloader-inner-half-circle"></span>
                                          </span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="swiper-zoom-container"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>`;
        }

2) /* If you need to render template as a popup */ renderPopup: function(){
                return `<div class="popup photo-browser-popup">
                            <div class="photo-browser photo-browser-dark">
                                <div class="view">
                                    <div class="page photo-browser-page photo-browser-page-dark no-toolbar ct-popup-browser" data-name="photo-browser-page">
                                        <div id="ct-popup-browser-inner">
                                            <div class="navbar">
                                                <div class="navbar-inner sliding">
                                                    <div class="left">
                                                        <a href="#" class="link popup-close icon-only" data-popup=".photo-browser-popup">
                                                            <i class="icon icon-back color-white"></i>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="title">
                                                        <span class="photo-browser-current"></span>
                                                        <span class="photo-browser-of">${getTranslationOrKey('of')}</span>
                                                        <span class="photo-browser-total"></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="right pd-lr-16">${dim}</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="toolbar tabbar toolbar-bottom-md">
                                                <div class="toolbar-inner">
                                                    <a href="#" class="link photo-browser-prev swiper-button-disabled" tabindex="0"
                                                       role="button"
                                                       aria-label="Previous slide" aria-disabled="true">
                                                        <i class="icon icon-back color-white"></i>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <a href="#" class="link photo-browser-next" tabindex="0" role="button"
                                                       aria-label="Next slide"
                                                       aria-disabled="false">
                                                        <i class="icon icon-forward color-white"></i>
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="photo-browser-captions photo-browser-captions-dark"></div>
                                            <div class="photo-browser-swiper-container swiper-container swiper-container-virtual swiper-container-horizontal swiper-container-rtl swiper-container-android">
                                                <div class="photo-browser-swiper-wrapper swiper-wrapper">
                                                    <div class="photo-browser-slide swiper-slide swiper-slide-active"
                                                         data-swiper-slide-index="0">
                                                        <span class="swiper-zoom-container"></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="photo-browser-slide photo-browser-slide-lazy swiper-slide swiper-slide-next"
                                                         data-swiper-slide-index="1">
                                                        <div class="preloader swiper-lazy-preloader color-white">
                                                            <span class="preloader-inner">
                                                              <span class="preloader-inner-gap"></span>
                                                              <span class="preloader-inner-left">
                                                                  <span class="preloader-inner-half-circle"></span>
                                                              </span>
                                                              <span class="preloader-inner-right">
                                                                  <span class="preloader-inner-half-circle"></span>
                                                              </span>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <span class="swiper-zoom-container"></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <span class="swiper-notification" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true"></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>`;
            },
```

Comment: Hi how can I use this example? Can you share any sample code?

Comment: Hi @HypeSol, just you need to add render function and put one of these html there..yu can look for render option from here: https://framework7.io/docs/photo-browser.html

Note: This code tested and work on Framwork7 v3, I check the v6 and option still exsits but I'm not sure if the html render still the same...